# How to pass parameters generated by a method to a Rust unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm trying to write a parametrized unit test in Rust, which will take parameters from a method. I know how to use [`rstest`](https://docs.rs/rstest/latest/rstest/) when parameters are hardcoded:

```
use rstest::rstest;

#[rstest]
#[case(42)]
#[case(256)]
fn my_test(#[case] x: i32) {
  assert!(x > 0)
}
```

However, I want something like this:

```
#[cases_from(my_provider)]
fn my_test(#[case] x: i32) {
  assert!(x > 0)
}

fn my_provider() -> Vec<i32> {
  [42, 256].to_vec()
}
```

Is is possible with `rstest`? If not, which library enables this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible with [rstest](https://crates.io/crates/rstest), though a similar feature has been asked for: [Issue #39: Dynamic set of tests](https://github.com/la10736/rstest/issues/39).  There is difficulty because the library is designed around generating individual test functions that are then ran and displayed separately by the standard `cargo test` harness. And to do that, the procedural macros at play need all the pieces. It is not implemented by a simple `for`-loop over the test cases.

If you simply desire a mechanism to use the same set of test cases for multiple tests, the developer has created the [rstest-reuse](https://crates.io/crates/rstest_reuse) crate which would be used like this:

```
#[template]
#[rstest]
#[case(2, 2)]
#[case(4/2, 2)]
fn two_simple_cases(#[case] a: u32, #[case] b: u32) {}

#[apply(two_simple_cases)]
fn it_works(a: u32, b: u32) {
    assert!(a == b);
}

#[apply(two_simple_cases)]
fn it_fail(a: u32, b: u32) {
    assert!(a != b);
}
```

If you're fine with a single test that loops over inputs (and therefore loses some visibility into which test failed and functionality to continue with other cases), then you can simply write that yourself:

```
#[test]
fn my_test() {
    fn my_test_inner(x: i32) {
        assert!(x > 0)
    }

    for x in my_provider() {
        my_test_inner(x);
    }
}

fn my_provider() -> Vec<i32> {
    [42, 256].to_vec()
}
```